# When is the onyomi of 田 used?

Tags: kanji, readings

My Kanji textbook mentions 田 to have the kunyomi た and the onyomi デン. デン is not mentioned in brackets so I conclude it is a very common reading.

But I hardly find any words that use デン. In an example in the book is a word 田水 written and it says its read でんすい, but there is no translation. I cannot find a translation of that word anywhere, but if I google the word I get たみず with explanation 田の水. Water on a rice field? That doesn't seem a common word at all! Can someone clarify this word and perhaps give examples of words where 田 is read als デン?

Thank you.

Comment: I usually discourage the use of edict, but... [http://jisho.org/words?jap=*%E7%94%B0*&eng=&dict=edict&common=on](http://jisho.org/words?jap=*%E7%94%B0*&eng=&dict=edict&common=on)

Comment: Hmm... it sounds like a typo of 水田. I think that ssb's link makes an almost comprehensive list of common デン words. I'd add to it 田野, 田楽 and ガス田. 桑田(そうでん, not くわた) is rarely seen in its literal meaning, instead used in the proverb 滄海(変じて)桑田(となす) for "the world changes unimaginably".

Comment: @ssb: Why do you discourage the use of edict and what do you offer as an alternative?

Comment: 田園調布 (Denenchoufu) - a rather well-to-do are in Setagaya-ku.

Comment: Regarding edict, it's just my opinion, but edict simply lists all possible translations for a given Japanese word or phrase, without explanations or usage examples. It is maintained by private persons. For example, the list of on-readings for each kanji lists many rare and obscure readings and should be revised, but that would require a lot of time. Also, it doesn't work well for English->Japanese. Sometimes, I feel some people are entering an English word in edict and post a question about the differences between all Japanese words they get.

Comment: Personally, I'm not using edict anymore at all, there are freely accessible monolingual and bilingual dictionaries available, eg. dic.search.yahoo.co.jp/. I suppose any further discussion on this topic should be done in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ssb [beta version of Jisho](http://beta.jisho.org/search/*%E7%94%B0*%20%E3%81%A7%E3%82%93%20%23words) is better. For one, data on old Jisho is outdated, for example に particle on [Jisho](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%AB&eng=&dict=edict) vs [beta Jisho](http://beta.jisho.org/word/51859fb0d5dda7295402f2be).

Comment: In addition to ssb's link, it's used in a bunch of place names. 新田（しんでん）is in the name of several places in Kansai that I know of, I think

Comment: 田園都市線 (runs from Chuo-Rinkan to Shibuya)

Comment: I've googled a bit and tried to find "田水" being read as "でんすい" but couldn't find anything, all "でんすい" I find is "田酔". I don't think that's an actual word.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few 田 words which use the デン reading. Each of them is a kind of field or plantation. **水田 is すいでん (paddy field)** (でんすい sounds like a typo), 油田 is ゆでん (oil field) and 桑田 is そうでん (mulberry field). The 水 in 水田 is present because it's a water-filled (irrigated) paddy field.

Source - Both Google and Obenkyo (android app)

Comment: Another word I've seen several times is 田園風景【でんえんふうけい】

Answer (score 0):

塩田{えんでん} -　[Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%A1%A9%E7%94%B0&safe=off&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=0dqIVMHjOdWyoQSSn4DQAg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg&biw=1680&bih=935)